# fabric 2.3.2 : network.sh cannot create all the container

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

[creating container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEICb.png)

I wrote a docker-compose.yaml to deploy 4 peers of org1 and 1 peer of org2, it worked. But when I write a docker-compose-100peer.yaml file to start 100 peers of org1 and 1 peer of org2, it always stuck in the situation shown in the picture. It never starts more than 30 peer of org1 even if I wait for a whole afternoon and a whole night. The original yaml file (docker-compose-test-net.yaml) dont't limit the memory an cpu resource.

peer5.org1.example.com:

```
container_name: peer5.org1.example.com

image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest

labels:

  service: hyperledger-fabric

environment:

- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=fabric_test

- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO

- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true

- CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=false

- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt

- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key

- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt

- CORE_PEER_ID=peer5.org1.example.com

- CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer5.org1.example.com:6010

- CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:6010

- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer5.org1.example.com:6011

- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:6011

- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer5.org1.example.com:6010

- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer5.org1.example.com:6010

- CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

- CORE_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:16010

volumes:

- ${DOCKER_SOCK}/:/host/var/run/docker.sock

- ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer5.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

- ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer5.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls

- peer5.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

command: peer node start

ports:

- 6010:6010

- 16010:16010

networks:

- test
```

peer6.org1.example.com:

```
container_name: peer6.org1.example.com

image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest

labels:

  service: hyperledger-fabric

environment:

- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=fabric_test

- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO

- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true

- CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=false

- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt

- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key

- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt

- CORE_PEER_ID=peer6.org1.example.com

- CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer6.org1.example.com:6012

- CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:6012

- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer6.org1.example.com:6013

- CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:6013

- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer6.org1.example.com:6012

- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer6.org1.example.com:6012

- CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

- CORE_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:16012

volumes:

- ${DOCKER_SOCK}/:/host/var/run/docker.sock

- ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer6.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

- ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer6.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls

- peer6.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

command: peer node start

ports:

- 6012:6012

- 16012:16012

networks:

- test
```

......
cli:

```
container_name: cli

image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest

labels:

  service: hyperledger-fabric

tty: true

stdin_open: true

environment:

- GOPATH=/opt/gopath

- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO

  #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG

working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

command: /bin/bash

volumes:

- ../organizations:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/organizations

- ../scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/

depends_on:

- peer0.org1.example.com

- peer0.org2.example.com

- peer1.org1.example.com

- peer2.org1.example.com

- peer3.org1.example.com

- peer4.org1.example.com

- peer5.org1.example.com

- peer6.org1.example.com

- peer7.org1.example.com
```

Comment: cli:depends_on: doesn't show all. It has 100 peers.

Comment: I do this work on VMware. OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Look for restarting/exited containers with `docker ps -a` and take a look to their logs. You can also take a look to the general docker logs with `sudo journalctl -fu docker.service`. You should be able to find some errors or warnings in the logs.

Comment: @kekomal `xtables contention detected while running` may be the source of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I still didn't solve the problem perfectly. Sometimes the 100 peers start normally, while sometimes the docker process stuck with only 20~30 peers successfully created. Maybe 100 peers deployed in a single Ubuntu system(in VMware) is not supported.

Comment: Should I fix some parameters in core.yaml and order.yaml to make the sample network able to support more peers communicate?